# Find the least integer k such that f(n) is O(nk) for log(n!)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

I'm trying to get the hang of big O. I know the answer is supposed to be k=2, but whenever I try using my thought process for this problem I get k=1 as the result:
I get that log(n!) = log(n)+log(n-1)+...+log(1)
From there I have: log(n)+log(n-1)+...+log(1)<=n+log(n)+log(n-1)+...+log(1), and since (and this is where I think I am wrong) n+log(n)+log(n-1)+...+log(1)is O(n), log(n!) = O(n)
An explanation on why I am wrong and how to work this problem would by very much appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Actually $\log(n!) \sim n \log n$ and Stirling's approximation will give a tighter approximation.  Your expansion shows it is $O(n\log n)$. Did you mean $O(n^2)$?

Comment: The problem in your analysis is failing to account for how many summands you have in $\log(n) + \log(n-1) + \ldots + \log(1)$, and sticking $n$ in front of everything does not avoid your responsibility to do so.

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.